# Limit Select2 to only one search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i want to know how to limit the search on select2 to only 1 search, i know the plugin have a option to set the maximum input lenght, but when use it the user can't write. I need a search with minimum 4 letters, and then no more petitions to server. Hope someone can help me.

Edit. Here a example Code of my actual Select2.

```
function formatResult(node) {
    return '<div>' + node.something + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + node.something + '</div>';
}

function formatSelection(node) {
    return '<div>' + node.something + ' ' + '-' + ' ' + node.something + '</div>';
}

$("#element").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "api_url",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 2250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                search: params,
                page: 10,
                format: 'json'
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data.results
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    formatResult: formatResult,
    formatSelection: formatSelection
});
```

Comment: Please include some sample code

Comment: What do you mean 'one search'? What defines a 'search' in this case?

Comment: @Parker i want only a one petition to server after the person write 4 letters or more, (actually the select2 make a petition to server for each letter after the minimumInputLength)

Comment: If they type 4 letters, then delete 2, are they allowed to ping the server again? I may have a solution, I just need to know the full logic. Also, do you want it to stop calling the server? Or just have it stop returning? If you explain your reasoning for this constraint, there may be easier workarounds

Comment: @Parker i want to stop calling the server. bassically need the user type, and after the 4 letters start the server calling after that, stop any server calling.

Answer (score 1):

change `minimumInputLength` to `maximumInputLength`.

This will show the user that they need to remove a character if they go over 4. Here's a rough example https://jsfiddle.net/4699tpsq/

Comment: That's works, but i have another question, is there any way to filter more the result witout make more ajax petitions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that AJAX calls stop once you go over, if not - there's no supported way in Select2. You could modify the AJAX url to go to nothing, in theory, but it's a tad hacky. May I ask why you're intent on preventing AJAX calls?